# The getter 'languageCode' isn't defined for the type 'List<Locale>'

Tags: flutter, localization

i need my application to support different languages.
But i have a problem using languageCode attribute.
**the code is:**

```
  supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', ''),
        Locale('ar', ''),
      ],
      localeListResolutionCallback: (currentLocale, supportedLocales) {
        if (currentLocale != null) {
          print(currentLocale.languageCode);
          for(Locale locale in supportedLocales){
           // if(currentLocale.languageCode== )
          }
        }
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
```

**the problem is :**
The getter 'languageCode' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try importing the library that defines 'languageCode', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'languageCode'.

Comment: You can upvote if the answer is helped :)  
      https://stackoverflow.com/a/64442099/10659482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code currentLocale is an array. You should define it locales for more correct name. You need to use it like this:

```
    localeListResolutionCallback: (locales, supported) {
          locales.forEach((l) => print(l.languageCode));
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete 'List' text from 'localeListResolutionCallback'.